# Order of occurance of the same value in a vector

Tags: r

I have the following series of numbers:

```
    id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1)
```

What is the most straightforward way to devise a vector including the order of each occurrence of each distinct number?

```
orders = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
ave(id, id, FUN=seq_along)
```

Or

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(id)$.id
```