# Generateing a per-group sequence based on a specific value in an existing column

Tags: r

Related to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063958/order-of-occurance-of-the-same-value-in-a-vector) - given the following data frame

```
df0 <- data.frame (id  = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                   val = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
```

what is the most straightforward way (i.e. one liner) to add a third column in which, for each `id`, sequence numbers appear only when `val == 1`, like the following?

```
   id val  seq
1   1   0    NA
2   1   1    1
3   1   1    2
4   2   0    NA
5   2   0    NA
6   2   0    NA
7   3   1    1
8   3   0    NA
9   3   1    2
10  3   1    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df0)[val == 1L, seq := seq_len(.N), by=id]
#     id val seq
#  1:  1   0  NA
#  2:  1   1   1
#  3:  1   1   2
#  4:  2   0  NA
#  5:  2   0  NA
#  6:  2   0  NA
#  7:  3   1   1
#  8:  3   0  NA
#  9:  3   1   2
# 10:  3   1   3
```

`.N` contains the number of observations per group. Start with [the HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for more.

Answer (score 1):

With `0` instead of `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)

df0 <- df0 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(seq = (val==1)*cumsum(val))
```

with `NA`

```
df0[df0$seq==0, 3] <- NA
```